# Nomes das medalhas estão todos em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização, medalhas

Hoje o site passou a mostrar os nomes de todas as medalhas em inglês, ignorando as traduções que já existiam. Isso pode ser visto em qualquer página onde apareçam medalhas, como na [lista de medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), nos perfis, etc., tanto no site principal quanto no meta.

Parece um bug introduzido no último build.

Comment: será que já consertaram? pra mim tá normal

Comment: É, parece que consertaram... O número do build (no rodapé) agora é `rev 2014.3.14.1460`, antes se não me engano era `1458`.

Comment: Faltou publicar um resource file, pelo visto.